# How to view the variable values in release builds

Tags: windows, windbg, visual-studio-debugging

I want to be able to see the variable values while debugging a release application. 
I have set the compiler option as Z7 and given a /DEBUG and /PDB: linker option. Now I have a pdb for the application.

With this set up I am able to put a break point (Windbg) inside the code and it hits properly. But I am not able to see the variable values.

The Locals window only shows the pointer value but I cant see the contents of the same. For instance if I have a pointer to a structure that has an int inside it, it just shows the value of the pointer. If I expand the same by clicking + in the tree, I see the variable name with the value as `<Memory access error>`

How should I make the release builds show the variable values?

Answer (score 1):

Many times, you cannot see them because they don't exist. If you look at the optimized assembly code, you will find that many intermediate variables are completely removed in favor of performance. That is most likely what you're seeing, and the only way around it is to follow the disassembly and watch the right memory locations / registers.

Comment: I dont think the optimization is the case here. I am not able to even the persistent objects.

Comment: take a look at the disassembly - you will see that at the point of the breakpoint, the state of variables & registers is not as clean & distinct as in debug mode. Things are done in a different order, and the pointer you care about is probably not even accessible.

Comment: I am inside a class function, still i am not able to see the contents of this pointer.

Comment: even in a class, there is no guarantee that there is even a `this` pointer in the final executable. Usually though it will be in the `ecx` register. You could try that just for kicks but i don't think it will help... put `(MyClass*)@ecx` in the watch window (i *think* that's the syntax)